# Objective-C - document header and not code file?

Tags: objective-c, headerdoc

I would like to start documenting my code properly, but am unsure where the best place is to put it for HeaderDoc to read. I read [the following phrase in the HeaderDoc documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/usage/usage.html) which makes me think the intended location (from Apple's point of view) is in the header files?

> Instead of specifying a single input file (as above), you can specify an input directory if you wish. HeaderDoc will process every .h file in the input directory (and all of its subdirectories), generating an output directory of HTML files for each header that contains HeaderDoc comments.

Is this right? Does it make a different where I put my documentation?